# Access Images In External Storage Created By My App

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-contentresolver, android-external-storage

I need a method to access the images stored in external storage by my app.

I want to access those images without requesting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` from the user

I'm using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to get the image from the user.

```kotlin
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
        val uri : String = it.data?.data?.toString()?:"null"
        if (uri != "null"){
            val mimeType = context.contentResolver.getType(uri.toUri()).toString()
            it.data?.data?.let {
                returnUri ->
                context.contentResolver.query(returnUri, null, null, null, null)
            }?.use { cursor ->
                val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                val size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
                image = image.copy(
                    path = uri, mimeType = mimeType.replace("image/",""), size = size,
                    name = name, uri = it.data?.data
                )
            }
        }else{
            image = image.copy(path = uri)
        }
    }
```

Calling the launcher for result

```kotlin
launcher.launch(Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*"))
```

After performing the required actions on the image, I save the image using the following method.

```kotlin
fun saveFile(context : Context, file: File) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            try {
                val values = ContentValues()
                val path = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/FolderName"
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, file.name)
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/*")
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, path)
                val savedFile = context.contentResolver.insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
                val outputStream = savedFile?.let {
                    context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(it)
                }
                val fis = FileInputStream(file)
                var length : Int
                val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
                while (fis.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0)
                    outputStream?.write(buffer, 0, length)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Picture saved to $path", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                println("Picture : $path / $savedFile")
            }catch (e : IOException){
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "An error occured while saving the file",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }catch (e : Exception) { e.printStackTrace() }
        }else{
            try {
                val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).absolutePath + "/FolderName"
                val image = File(dir, file.name)
                val fis = FileInputStream(file)
                val fos = FileOutputStream(image)
                var length : Int
                val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
                while (fis.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, length)
                }
            }catch (e : IOException){
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "An Error occurred while saving the file",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                e.printStackTrace()
            }catch (e : Exception) { e.printStackTrace() }
        }
    }
```

psst ~ All of these actions are performed without requesting any permissions.

When I'm trying to access images from contentResolver, it always returns 0.

```kotlin
private fun loadImages() : List<Image> {

        val photos = mutableListOf<Image>()

        val collection = sdk29andUp {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        } ?: MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED
        )

        contentResolver.query(
            collection, projection, null, null, null
        )?.use { cursor ->

            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            val displayNameColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val dateAddedColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED)

            cursor.moveToFirst()
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                val name = cursor.getString(displayNameColumn)
                val date = cursor.getLong(dateAddedColumn)

                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    id
                )

                photos.add(
                    Image(
                        id = id, name = name, entryDate = date, contentUri = contentUri
                    ))

            }


        }
        return photos.toList()
    }
```

If someone can help me with this, I would really appreciate that.

**Edit :** The app crashes on API 28 and Before, so I'll have to request permissions for those API levels, but it means there is a solution for api's after 28

Comment: Why are you using ACTION_GET_CONTENT ? You save your files using the mediastore. So you know all uris. You even can list them using the mediastore. Please tell your scenario. Put your scenario at the first lines of your post.

Comment: You should use the same collection at insert() and query().

Comment: Tell Android version of used device.

Comment: ty for your comment @blackapps , I didn't understand what u meant by the scenario, but the reason behind `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is I want an image from a user, perform the actions on that image then save it in a folder. I've tried this behavior on Android 10, Android 13 and Andoid 7 (Crashes on Android 7 due to SecurityException so will need to request permissions before Android 9)

Comment: @blackapps I'm having a hard time understanding this where it says `No permissions needed if you only access your own media files` at : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#request-permissions , How can I retrieve images I stored?

Comment: You did not answer my first two comments.

Comment: @blackapps I did answer it, I posted 2 comments ;-; | Also I'm using the same collection at `insert()` and `query()` now

Comment: Don't know if this is what u mean by scenario, but I want the user to be able to see the images they processed in my app, **The Images processed by my app**, and for that, I need to get the images from the mediaStore at a later point

Comment: I cannot see that you use the same collection. Please post only code for SDK 28 and post the stacktrace. And google for the meaning of scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with a very straight forward implementation. Posting the code in hopes that it will help someone.

This implementation covers all API levels from 21 to 33

### Saving the image

```kotlin
/** import MediaStore.Images.Media to remove Redundant typing of MediaStore.Images.Media **/
private fun saveImage(file: File) {
        sdk29andUp {
            val collection = Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
            val path = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name)
            val values = ContentValues().apply {
                put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, file.name)
                put(Media.SIZE, file.length())
                put(Media.RELATIVE_PATH, path)
            }

            contentResolver.insert(collection, values)?.also { uri ->
                contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { outputStream ->
                    val fis = FileInputStream(file)
                    var length : Int
                    val buffer =  ByteArray(8192)
                    while (fis.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0)
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
                }
                println(uri)
            } ?: throw IOException("Error creating entry in mediaStore")
        } ?: saveImageBefore29(file)
    }

    private fun saveImageBefore29(file: File) {
        val resolver = contentResolver
        val collection = Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).absolutePath + "/${getString(R.string.app_name)}"
        val directory = File(dir)
        if (!directory.exists())
            directory.mkdirs()
        val image = File(dir, file.name).also { println(it) }
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, image.name)
            put(Media.SIZE, image.length())
            put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png")
            put(Media.DATA, image.path)
        }
        resolver.insert(collection, values)?.also { uri ->
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { outputStream ->
                val fis = FileInputStream(file)
                var length : Int
                val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
                while (fis.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0)
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length)
            }
        }

    }
```

`sdk29andUp` function ->

```kotlin
inline fun <T> sdk29andUp(onSdk29: () -> T) : T? =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        onSdk29() 
    else null
```

Some things I want to point out are:

**API 29 and above:**
Creating the folder you want to save the file in before this function would result in `IllegalArgumentException` as your app doesn't own that folder. Just insert the folder path in `RELATIVE_PATH` and resolver will create the folder in which your app can write freely.

**API 28 and below:**
You will need to create the folder yourself in these API levels while also requesting the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` & `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` from the user.

### Loading The Images

```kotlin
private fun loadImages() : List<Image> {
        return sdk29andUp {

            val imagesList = mutableListOf<Image>()
            val collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
            val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED
            )

            contentResolver.query(
                collection,
                projection,
                null, null,
                null
            )?.use { cursor ->
                val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
                val nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)

                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                    val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
                    val date = cursor.getLong(dateColumn)

                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(collection, id).also { println("URI $it") }
                    imagesList += Image(
                        id = id, name = name, path = contentUri.path.toString(),
                        contentUri = contentUri, entryDate = date
                    )
                }
                imagesList
            }

        } ?: loadImagesBefore29()
    }

    private fun loadImagesBefore29() : List<Image> {
        val images = mutableListOf<Image>()
        val collection = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        )

        val selection = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA} like ? "
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%${getString(R.string.app_name)}%")


        contentResolver.query(
            collection,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null
        )?.use { cursor ->
            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            val nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN)
            val dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
                val date = cursor.getLong(dateColumn)
                val data = cursor.getString(dataColumn)

                val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    collection, id
                ).also { println("Uri $it") }

                images += Image(
                    id = id, name = name, path = data,
                    contentUri = contentUri, entryDate = date
                )

            }

        }
        return images
    }
```

When loading the images on API level 29 and above, if your app doesn't have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` permission granted, ContentResolver will only query the MediaStore for images/files your app created.

On API level 28 and below, I'm querying a specific folder as the app holds `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` so contentResolver will return all images in MediaStore if no `selectionArgs` are specified.

Hope I was able to explain this and help someone with this.